# Prove that for the differentiable $f(x)$ with a root $r$ of multiplicity $n$ necessitates that all derivatives up till $f^{(n-1)}(r)=0$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, roots

This statement appears in Numerical Analysis by Sauer:

Assume that $r$ is a root of the differentiable function
$f$; that is , assume that $f(r)=0$. Then if $0=f(r)=f'(r)=f''(r)=...=f^{(m-1)}(r)$, but $f^{(m)}\ne 0$, we say that $f$ has a **root** of **multiplicity** $m$ at $r$.

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial this statement is provably true by the fact that $f(x)=(x-r)g(x)$ for a function $g(x)$ which has a polynomial grade one less than $f(x)$. Because $f(x)$ is differentiable $\frac{d((x-r)g(x))}{dx}=g(x)+(x-r)g'(x)$. If $f'(r)=0\Rightarrow g(r)=0 \Rightarrow g(x)=(x-r)h(x)\Rightarrow f(x)=(x-r)^2h(x)$

My question is how you prove that this statement is true for all differentiable functions?

Comment: The statement you mention is not a proposition. It is a definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a definition. In the particular case of polynomials, having multiplicity $k$ is equivalent to having a factor $(x-r)^k$ in the factorization. What you can prove for a more general function is that, if $r$ is a root of multiplicity $k$ then
$$
\lim_{x\to r}\frac{f(x)}{(x-r)^{k-1}}=0.
$$

Comment: Is this a local behaviour around $x\rightarrow r$ or is $f(x)=(x-r)^k h(x)$ true for all $x$ given some $h$?

Comment: These are equivalent. If $f$ has a root of multiplicity $k$ at $x=r$, you can factor $f$ as $f(x)=(x-r)^kh(x)$, where $h$ is a continuous function with $h(r)\neq 0$.